# Printing Height in Java

Tags: java

I have a printer that looks like: http://www.wepindia.com/products/Productspage.aspx?item=POS-0046

It contains a paper roll for continuous printing. While printing in Java the problem is that the printing stops at halfway through (I guess something is limiting the height)

Here's the code used (used to set the paper height):

```
PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
Paper paper = new Paper();
double margin = 1;
paper.setImageableArea(margin, margin, 10, 10000);
paper.setSize(200, 10000);
pf.setPaper(paper);
```

Is there a way to remove the height of page, so that the paper could be contineous?

Thanks

Comment: FYI: There was once a JavaPOS library http://www.javapos.com/samplecode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java class `Paper` was designed for sheets of paper.  The entire `java.awt.print` package was designed with sheet printers in mind.

If you're going to use `java.awt.print`, you could make your page size smaller and print multiple pages.

If you're printing transactions, multiple pages will probably work.

If you're logging, there's probably some upper limit on the number of pages you can print in one `PrinterJob`.

As PeterMmm mentioned in his comment, you could use a third party package like [JavaPOS](http://www.javapos.com/).